# Error when passing object of type DataStream from Controller to a view with Apache flink and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-flink

I'm new to flink and I'm facing a problem in displaying an object of type DataStream (Apache flink) in a webpage view using Spring boot and thymeleaf. Is it possible to convert this DataStream object to a list to be passed to the view? 
When I just pass the DataStream object as a parameter to the view like this:

```
List<String> inputFeed = Serializefeed(entries);
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<String> feeds = env.fromCollection(inputFeed);
DataStream<String> AnnotatedFeed = feeds.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String map(String SingleFeed) throws Exception {
            /**
                Some operations on the Stream
             **/
        }
    }).setParallelism(10);
    model.addAttribute("feedsAnnotated",AnnotatedFeed);
    env.execute("Rss feed Annotater example");

    return "AnnotatedFeed";
}
```

And display it in the view using AnnotatedFeed.print();
I get an exception: Method call: Attempted to call method print() on null context object.
So any help how can i store the DataStream into an object that can be passed to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how i solved it by saving the datastream in a collection and then passing that collection to my view:

```
Iterator<Object> iter = DataStreamUtils.collect(datastream);
List<Object> list = Lists.newArrayList(iter);
```